# How to fetch Smart Goals for GA account?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm having trouble listing the goals created with the recently launched [Smart Goals](http://analytics.blogspot.fi/2015/12/use-smart-goals-powered-by-google.html) feature. They appear in the GA user interface in the goals list, but not in the API.

The API documentation doesn't mention anything about Smart Goals and I assumed they would be listed alongside normal goals in the results from [the goals API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list). However, fetching all goals won't list the Smart Goals based on a few tries.

Has any else run into this issue?

Comment: It can take a while before new features in the website are released to the API.  My guess is its not part of the API yet.   I would add it as an issue request https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: Good point! Added feature request about it: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=883&ts=1455710372

Comment: Any news regarding this?

Comment: Hi @AnttiPitkänen, were you able to eventually find a workaround to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick around this problem.

You can build a segment that includes users/sessions (depends on what you are looking for) that have more than 0 completions.

Then in the query, set the segment to the one you just created and you will get what you are looking for.

- One thing - Smart goals might change and the way you build the segment is true about now. it could be that if there were significant changes in the smart goals, you would not extract correct data.

Comment: Hi @yaron can you please provide api calls for the steps mentioned? (optionally java com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics sample would be nice :) )